# Plotly dash server side caching

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using server side caching in my `dash` application and I've followed example 4 in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks). I'm using this to query and process the "global" data, this prepared dataset is then shared between the different components in the application.

This works fine; the data loads when I load or refresh the application.

But the data also reloads when I've left the application for a couple of minutes and come back (e.g. visiting another tab in the browser without closing the app). So what I'm confused around is how these sessions work and why they seem to expire so quickly. What is the approach to control this? E.g. via increasing allowed idle time or strictly renewing the session on page load/refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memoized data is refreshed when one of three things happen,

1. The value(s) of the input argument(s) change
2. The cache has expired
3. The cache has been cleared

In the example in your link, a new `uuid` is generated on each page load. This id is passed as an argument to the memoized function, and the data will thus be refreshed on page load due to (1).

If more than a predefined timeout has passed ([default value is 300 seconds](https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-caching/blob/5eef6738430a6887fce03552cb2438501e3dc741/flask_caching/__init__.py#L175))), the data will be refreshed as per (2). That's probably why you're experiencing that "*the data also reloads when I've left the application for a couple of minutes and come back*". You can adjust timeout to your needs via the `CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` parameter of the `Cache` object or via the `timeout` keyword of the `memoize` decorator.

In addition, the cache will be refreshed if the data cannot be found (3). Besides manual deletion, this can happen if the cache runs out of space. Per default, [500 cache elements are kept](https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-caching/blob/5eef6738430a6887fce03552cb2438501e3dc741/flask_caching/__init__.py#L177). This number can be adjusted via the `CACHE_THRESHOLD` argument of the Cache object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifcation! Is there any way to stop the cache expiration while the page is being actively used? The expiration is nice in general, however it's annoying if the data refreshes out of nowhere while working with the dashboard.

Comment: Also, in the example I linked to, it seems like there is a cache element stored for each callback that references the session id. At the same time, it says that the threshold should be set to the maximum number of concurrent users. But if there are, say, 5 users and 2 callbacks referencing the session id, the threshold should be set to 10. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no built-in features that enable that kind of behavior, but you could of course implement it yourself. However, you could achieve almost the same behavior simply by setting the timeout to a very large value (so that data is never reloaded during a session) and the threshold to a reasonable value (so that the cache size does not grow too much). The latter would typically be something along the lines of (number of memoized callbacks) x (number of concurrent users).